# Boolean function for binary shift with a variable amount

Tags: binary, bitwise-operators, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

How can I construct a Boolean function for a binary *shift* operation by a variable amount?

I looked that there are possibilities using *and* and *or* operators *[Binary Shifters using Logic Gates](https://www.101computing.net/binary-shifters-using-logic-gates/)*. But my problem is I need to do a *shift* operation by a variable amount and not hardcoding this variable to 1.

Answer (score 0):

For each A input, add an AND gate for each possible value of the shift.  The inputs to these gates will be its A and a new D selector value for the value of the shift.  There will be (8 possible shift values) X (8 bits) = 64 of these AND gates.

The Boolean functions for each of these new D selectors can be determined by using truth tables and [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).  These gates can then be reduced/re-used.  This will be a large circuit!

You could look for a chip that provides this function--the documentation for it might show the circuit diagram.